# strange issue when using drawer in Android lollipop

Tags: android, drawer

I have mainlayout.xml as coded below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    tools:context="com.sanwix.mh.meeting.MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/layout_appbar"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/MyMainReycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:padding="16dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/Fabb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
            android:transitionName="sharedFab"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:elevation="8dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecycleDrawer"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

every things work perfectly on pre-lollipop devices. 
but on lollipop or above, it doesn't run perfectly.
my issue is that: I have no main content for myactivity
and each one of my elements take a seperate drawer .
I mean the RelativeLayout will be shown as left-side drawer
and the RecyclerView will be shown as right-side drawe on lollipop or above.
but 
what I want is just one drawer on rightside(my recycle)

Comment: That layout really shouldn't behave as you're describing, unless there's some bug in a newer support library version I've not heard of. Try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: @MikeM. i did it several times but no chenges

Comment: Well, I had a quick look through the current source, and that shouldn't happen, from what I can tell. You might try explicitly setting a `layout_gravity` of `center_horizontal` on the `RelativeLayout`. If that doesn't work, you might have to fiddle with the layout programmatically.

Comment: Please, add some pictures that describe the problem in details

Comment: @MikeM.i got this error after i added layout_gravity of c_h on relativelayoutv : Child drawer has absolute gravity RIGHT but this DrawerLayout already has a drawer view along that edge
                                                                         at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1089)

Comment: OK, after looking at how `DrawerLayout` checks its children's gravity, that's what should happen, so that won't work. If you're not doing anything in your code that messes with the `DrawerLayout` and its children, then you might have encountered a bug. If that's so, then you might try altering the `RelativeLayout`'s `LayoutParams` in code, after `setContentView()`. You'd want to `getLayoutParams()` on it, cast those to `DrawerLayout.LayoutParams`, set the `gravity` field to `Gravity.NO_GRAVITY`, then `setLayoutParams()`/`requestLayout()` on it.